# "Be going to" vs "future continuous"

Tags: grammar

I know that when we have fixed arrangements about a plan, we use present continuous.

Example: We are visiting X city next week. Would you like to join with us?

-> All things have been arranged. I already decided the time, bought flight tickets...

But when there are not fixed arrangements about a plan. We use be going to or future continuous instead. Right?
So what is the difference between "be going to" and "future continuous"
We only decided to visit X city but haven't made any arrangements.

> (1) We are going to visit  X city next week. Would you like to join
> with us?
>
> (2)We will be visiting X city next week. Would you like to join with
> us?

Is that "be going to" is more certain to happen than the future continuous here?

Answer (score 1):

If you have made the travel arrangements you can use either the present continuous, future continuous or 'are going to'. So *We're visiting X, We will be visiting X* and *We're going to visit X* are all possible ways to say it.

If  no firm arrangements have been made, you could say *we hope to visit, we plan to visit* or *we are thinking of visiting X.*

Comment: If you have made the travel arrangements you can use either the present continuous, future continuous or 'are going to'.-> no difference at all between these 2 tenses?

Comment: Not that I can think of - see my edit.

Comment: +1 I dunno why people don't upvote this kind of concise answer.

Comment: Hi Kate and Lambie, my grammar books say " I am visiting.." is used for fixed arrangements. " I am gong to visit" is used for intention. This made me confused.

Comment: You can use _going to_ if you have the definite intention of doing something, even if you haven't actually booked the tickets (or whatever). The alternatives I suggested were for less definite plans.

Comment: If the sentence has a time maker or not, they still have the same meaning. Right? For example: (1) Yesterday my glasses broke. I (am going to buy)/(will be buying) a new one.***** (2)Tomorrow the shop has a promotion, I ( am going to buy)/(will be buying) a new computer tomorrow.

Comment: (1) Yesterday I broke my glasses. I will be buying a new pair as soon as I can get to the optician's. (_Will be buying_ doesn't sound quite right without another time marker.) (2) is OK, but better not to repeat _tomorrow_.

Comment: These pairs of sentences are equally the same too. Right? (1) Are you going to visit X tomorrow?
(2) Will you be visiting X tomorrow?
***
(3) Are you going to bring a gift to the party tomorrow?
(4) Will you be bringing a gift to the party tomorrow?

Comment: Yes, I would consider them as meaning the same. (NB It's better to ask "Are these pairs of sentences the same?" than to make a statement and add "Right?".)

Comment: (1) Are you going to visit X tomorrow? (2) Will you be visiting X tomorrow? Do you think (2) sound more polite than (1)?. My grammar book say that the future continuous also can be used to ask about someone's plan politely.

Comment: Yes, it probably does sound a little more polite.